# Simplicial complex of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, simplicial-stuff

Starting with a graph $G$, form a simplicial complex $X$ which has $G$ as the 1-skeleton, and then has higher dimensional simplices whenever more than two vertices of $G$ are mutually adjacent. So any $n$ mutually adjacent vertices in $G$ will correspond to a $(n-1)$-simplex in $X$.

Is this a valid/common construction? Does it have a name? Thanks-

Comment: This is essentially the nerve of the path groupoid of your graph.

Answer (score 3):

Self-answer: This is the [clique complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex).